# IndexOutOfBoundsException in expandablelistview

Tags: android

```
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037): Process: com.btpl.events1, PID: 25037
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3307)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15430)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4114)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15230)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15324)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15230)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15228)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15324)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15230)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1089)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15228)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15228)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15228)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15228)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15228)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3406)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3199)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15324)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2653)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2654)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2567)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2356)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
10-05 11:10:21.434: E/AndroidRuntime(25037):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: And format your error log please.

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your ArrayList has 1 element, whose index should be zero.
Its trying to get an element with index 1 in an ArrayList with only 1 element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have edited, the answer, I meant ArrayList.